# python read Large integers in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, precision, int64

I have an excel with following 3 large integers (in fact, they are ids).
But in excel it will be stored in scientific mode.
And when I use pandas to read the excel, I will lost precision since the integer is too large for int64 to store it.

Example data: (1.xlsx)
76307016609101000000000000000000 
86412903902869300000000000000000 
35575701294198100000000000000000

```
A = pd.read_excel("1.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", header=None, dtype=np.float64) 
% no matter what the dtype is the result will be wrong

print(int(A.loc[0])) # 76307016609101001211632066494464 wrong
```

I don't know whether there's a type of int that's longer than int64 and supported by numpy/pandas. Thank you very much!!

Comment: open the excel in a text editor, find the xml node for that value, I bet you it is the same as what pandas is reading it as, pandas reads directly from the XML node as does Excel. However excel tries to guess what the datatype is and adds its own formatting onto the value.

Comment: If it is an ID, and you need the precision, store it in Excel as a text string.

Comment: can you share the excel in a github repo - it's hard to reproduce with an excel copied text I'll have a look at the XML for you

Comment: 76307016609101000000000000000000 
86412903902869300000000000000000 
35575701294198100000000000000000 

Cell type the numerical

Comment: @Manakin https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiI5NzdiNDUzNi05Yzk2LTRjNzQtYjNiNS1hYTM3ZmM5YzU2ODkiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImRkZDQ1OTI2QHByb3Rvbm1haWwuY29tIn0=

Comment: @Manakin or you can just copy those 3 lines and paste them into an empty xlsx file and I think you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Manakin I cannot open xlsx file with other text editors. I have tried Notepad++, notepad and vs code. I don't think they can open the xlsx as a xml file.

Comment: you first need to unzip the file change the ext to `.zip` then find the relevant xml file. I think its called worksheet.xml

Comment: the values I get in the xml file are [`7.6307016609101001E+31`,`8.6412903902869292E+31`, `3.5575701294198099E+31`] which is what i get when i open it with pandas.

Comment: @Manakin That coincides with my guess. What stores in excel is actually `7.6307016609101001E+31` not `76307016609101000000000000000000`. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get excel to spit out the raw numbers then you can get around this by reading the numbers as Text

```
import pandas as pd 
import io

txt='''\
line,Num,text
1,12345678901234435346789012345678901234567890,"large"
2,66464644666669999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999991,"larger"
3,1,"unity"
4,-9999999999999999999999999999999999999999,"larger in a different way"
'''

df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), converters={'Num':int})

print(df)
```

results in

```
   line                                                Num  \
0     1       12345678901234435346789012345678901234567890   
1     2  6646464466666999999999999999999999999999999999...   
2     3                                                  1   
3     4          -9999999999999999999999999999999999999999   

                        text  
0                      large  
1                     larger  
2                      unity  
3  larger in a different way
```

and you can still do sums on them

```
n=df["Num"][1]
print (n,n+1 )
```

yields

```
66464644666669999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999991 
66464644666669999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999992
```

Comment: df = pd.read_excel(f,engine='openpyxl',header=None,converters={0:int})
0 76307016609101001211632066494464 NHC12F19A01301980000000000000000
1 86412903902869292276650258464768 NaN
2 35575701294198099476429701906432 NaN
why me on xlsx  lost precision since

Comment: I think the problem is when the number is in excel(.xlsx), Excel will store it in scientific mode (76307016E+31, like this) and when pandas try to read the number, pandas will only get 76307016E+31 and numpy only support np.int64(which is not sufficient for this numbr) and np.float64(which cannot accurately store this large integer). I guess that's the problem.